# how to select alt and title in dreamweaver with regular expression?

Tags: regex, dreamweaver

How can I select all alt tag and title tag with it's content in dream weaver my alt and title pattern is like this alt='اتیتس لستلسی سیلب'
i try this but nto worked
alt=([^<]*)

```
<a href='http://janebi.ir/product/152112' class='imagelink'>
 <img class='product_thumb_image lazyOwl' alt='نگهدارنده سیم Adhesive Cable Clips' data-src='http://janebi.ir/janebi/9fd2/files/thumb/103174.jpg' />
</a>

<a itemprop="url" title='نگهدارنده سیم Adhesive Cable Clips' href='http://janebi.ir/product/152112' >
  <h3 itemprop="name">نگهدارنده سیم Adhesive Cable Clips</h3>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
alt='([^']*)'
```